# Override IEnumerable<T> Where

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I've written a class that implements IEnumerable :

```
public class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable<MyClass>
{ 
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //Enumerate
    }
}
```

I'd like to "override" the Where method. What I want to do is :

```
MyEnumerable myEnumerable = new MyEnumerable();
MyEnumerable myEnumerable2 = myEnumerable.Where(/*some predicate*/);
```

This is not possible for the moment because myEnumerable.Where() returns an IEnumerable.
What I want is that myEnumerable.Where() returns a MyEnumerable.

Is that possible to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you implementing your own Enumerable in the first place?  What does it buy you?  With `yield` and Linq it is increasingly rare to need to implement your own enumerable class.

Answer (score 5):

Sure - just add a `Where` method to `MyEnumerable`.  The Linq `Where` method is an *extension* method, so it's not technically an override. you're "hiding" the linq method.

```
public class MyEnumerable : IEnumerable<MyClass>
{ 
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public IEnumerator<MyClass> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //Enumerate
    }

    public MyEnumerable Where()
    {
       // implement `Where`
    }
}
```

There are some caveats, though:

- Your Where method will only be called if the declared type is `MyEnumerable` - it will not be called on variables of type `IEnumerable<MyClass>` (or any collection that implements it, like `List<MyClass>`
- There are several overloads of `Where` that will need to be implemented as well if you want to maintain consistently with Linq.

Comment: I *think* explicit extension for particular class will take preference over generic version - `public static MyEnumerable  Where(this IEnumerator<MyClass> sequence, ...)` so first caveat may be solved.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

From your comment your enumerator is a lazy file enumerator and you want to be able to select items from it based on a predicate and still have the laziness.

You could create another class inheriting that class or an interface to help with this.

### Here is an example

```
public class FileItem
{
    //Some properties
}

public interface IFileEnumerator : IEnumerable<FileItem>
{
    IFileEnumerator Where(Func<FileItem, bool> predicate);
}

public class FileEnumerator : IFileEnumerator
{
    private readonly string fileName;

    public FileEnumerator(string fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<FileItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var items = new List<FileItem>();

        //Read from file and add lines to items

        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IFileEnumerator Where(Func<FileItem, bool> predicate)
    {
        return new MemoryEnumerator(ToEnumerable(GetEnumerator()).Where(predicate));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator) 
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}

public class MemoryEnumerator : IFileEnumerator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<FileItem> items;

    public MemoryEnumerator(IEnumerable<FileItem> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<FileItem> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IFileEnumerator Where(Func<FileItem, bool> predicate)
    {
        return new MemoryEnumerator(items.Where(predicate));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to do something like that, but...
I read items from a file. So the items list is populated in GetEnumerator, to have a lazy loading. So when the Where method is called, items is null (or empty).

Comment: I made some changes based on your comment. Could this help you?

Comment: Thank you, it works. I've done Take and Concat on the same way.