# How do I override Skip() and Take()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, ienumerable

I need to somehow have Linq `Skip()` and `Take()` reimplemented such that they return the same set of items as the one they were applied to - skip nothing and take all. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32209253/57428) about overriding `Where()`. So I crafted this:

```
public interface IDataEnumerator<StoredItemType> : IEnumerable<StoredItemType>
{
    IDataEnumerator<StoredItemType> Skip(int count);
}

public class DataEnumerator<StoredItemType> : IDataEnumerator<StoredItemType>
{
    private IEnumerable<StoredItemType> storedItems;

    public DataEnumerator(IEnumerable<StoredItemType> items)
    {
        storedItems = items;
    }
    public IDataEnumerator<StoredItemType> Skip(int count)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public IDataEnumerator<StoredItemType> Take(int count)
    {
        return this;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<StoredItemType> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return storedItems.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

and here's the calling code:

```
IEnumerable<int> enumerator = new DataEnumerator<int>(new List<int>());
enumerator = enumerator.Take(1).Skip(1);
```

The constructor is called but `Skip()` and `Take()` from the class are not called. I don't get how this is different from that other answer with `Where()`.

What am I missing and how do I have custom `Skip()` and `Take()`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? _This smells a bit like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ._

Comment: The answer you linked to *specifically* tells you when it will and won't be called.

Comment: I have a very useful mechanism which accepts `IEnumerable` and the number of "page" and the size of "page" in it. Based on those parameters it calls `Skip()` and `Take()` to extract the "page" itself. I want to pass the size and count as usual but extract the page myself and pass it such that it's not filtered again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the linked answer:

> Your Where method will only be called if the declared type is MyEnumerable - it will not be called on variables of type `IEnumerable<MyClass>` (or any collection that implements it, like `List<MyClass>`.

You are storing the variable as an `IEnumerable` so it is still using the LINQ extension method.

Comment: Yes, and this is another case where `var` is useful again.

Comment: I mistakenly linked to the question itself. The question has two answers. Are the snippets in them equally affected by this restriction?

Comment: @Kit I did not use `var` exactly to indicate that the reference type is changed such as when passing it somewhere where `IEnumerable` is expected.

Comment: @sharptooth Based on my understanding of extension methods; yes both answers would be equally under this restriction. Your best bet would probably be to have a _different_ method like `TakePaged` or something so its very explicit what is being used (prevents dev confusion as well)

Comment: @sharptooth, I think you might want to consider giving the methods different names and implementing them as extensions. That way you can still use them on `IEnumerable<T>` and you avoid the confusion of the existing LINQ methods.

Comment: @Kit That would be great if only I had control of the code that calls `Skip()` and `Take()`.